# Connection to DB2

Tags: passwords, db2, registry

I'm new in querying the DB2. Am trying to run a select query in DB2 and get the results in a datatable using a C# Windows Application.

Below are the issues which am facing.

1. I used IBM.Data.DB2.dll as reference but am still getting errors for the classes like **DB2Connection, DB2Adapter, etc**.
2. Want to fetch the password from registry for a particular user ID. Am completely unaware of how that can be done. I want this to mention in the Connection string.

Kindly help me on these queries..
Thanks in Advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at the official [C# Samples](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.samptop.doc/doc/r0011079.html) for DB2.
2. Take a look at for instance this example for managing Windows registry using C#.[enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)